# How to apply a linear-gradient background to a table row in IE9?

Tags: css

I want to apply a linear-gradient background to a table row.

Here's the .css:

```
<style type="text/css">
 .contentBody{
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #95b83d 0%, #abca5e 100%);
   background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #95b83d 0%, #abca5e 100%);
   background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #95b83d 0%, #abca5e 100%);
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient (startColorstr='#ff95b83d', endColorstr='#ffabca5e', GradientType=1);
  }
...
</style>
```

And here's the .html:

```
<table>
  <tr class="contentBody"> Heading</tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I am doing wrong here? Why the gradient isn't shown?

Comment: IE9 does not support linear gradients. To get linear gradients in IE9 you usually have to use SVG as outlined [here](http://css3wizardry.com/2010/10/29/css-gradients-for-ie9/)

Answer (score 0):

well, "Heading" text has to be wrapped with a `td` like so:

```
<table>
  <tr class="contentBody"><td>Heading</td></tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```